# How to get the result from a many to many table using HQL

Tags: java, hql

I have two tables, *Employee* and *Projects*, with a many-to-many relationship. How should I write a HQL to get all projects that an employee is working for?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a query. If you've setup the relationship with a `@ManyToMany` then you can just get an Employee and then `employee.getProjects()` will return the correct data.

```
public class Employee {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "employee_project",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Collection<Project> projects;

}

public class Project {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "employee_project",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Collection<Employee> employees;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Sorry i am a novice in java.... then how can i create an api or "method " in service implementaion file of Employee/Project class?

Comment: That's a different question.